# Synchronisation of topics across different signed in users

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently trying to migrate from Parse to Firebase Cloud Messaging. I am currently having an issue migrating from Parse's "add/remove channels" to FCM's "subscribe/unsubscribe topics".

My use case: upon users sign in, client side will fetch a list of topics this user is interested in. Client side will then subscribe to all the topics in this list by looping through the list.

When a user adds a new entry to this list, subscribe to this new topic.
When a user removes a topic from the list, unsubscribe from this topic.

When a user signs out, unsubscribe from all topics.

This is where I am having problem: should I loop through the list and unsubscribe from the topic one by one? Or is there a simpler way of achieving the same result?

I have tried `- (void)deleteIDWithHandler:(nonnull FIRInstanceIDDeleteHandler)handler;` to reset the old ID and fetch a new one. But the new ID doesn't always receive topic message.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is the correct one, there have been requests for batch subscribe and unsubscribe, the FCM team is looking at implementing this but it is not available yet, so subscribing one by one is the best option at the moment.